# How is it possible to set DOORS requirement's state according to state of ALM task?

Tags: alm, ibm-doors, ibm-jazz

There is a requirement in DOORS and this have a *state* (e.g. Tested, Implemented) attribute. This requirement has a link to an ALM PCR. This PCR has some link to tasks (e.g. Implementation, Test).

I have to develop an application, which follow for all requirements in DOORS the link to the ALM PCR object (if have link). Then follow the PCR's links to the task and according to task's state set the state of the requirement. This need for the trace-ability. So if one task has done than run the application it will change the requirement state in DOORS.

[The system looks like this](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&target=blank&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7VpZk5s4EP41foxKFwI9zpHdzVaySWVSlewjtjU2O9g4GM%2F167cFEkgGx8dgxzlGVYxpCbX4%2BlN3S2LArmaPf%2BbxYvouG6t0QPH4ccCuB5QSzjD805KnShJyI5jkydg0agQ3ybMyQttslYzV0mtYZFlaJAtfOMrmczUqPFmc59mD3%2Bw2S32ti3iiWoKbUZy2pZ%2BTcTGtpFGAG%2FlfKplMrWaCTc0wHt1N8mw1N%2FoGlN2Wf1X1LLZ9mfbLaTzOHhwRez1gV3mWFdWv2eOVSjW2FrbquT821NbjztW82OUByqsn7uN0peyQy4EVTxYM%2FT6LAbu8zebFjRHjtiKj%2B17lhXrsslI8tD02bwoMUtlMFfkTtDNPWa4Y7ljQHxpDkBq%2FqWOFUAaGAcb6k7rrBgH4YUDoBiTaFY%2FW%2B9dQvhgAwZGQbmkBwIRAkvKmtNGgIkI4IkwGjEcRC%2BnLsaHbsSmpr3R7Aox5mCaFulnEI137AK4CZNNilprqOB%2BZqU%2F0bRvSaAOibeS%2BOzasAxuRgr7LIfyYFOX7VYKVFVy%2Ff%2F%2FxxkpBwWq9Jcicp9egBkgKH89lkWd36ipLsxwk82yu9KxN0nRNFKfJZA63IwBagfxSA5yA97swFbNkPNZqOg34EjPZWiKRDATGlDGir96EpwRxLgJCBExpLGQYdDiAEGHwAiwMRXllbSMzigg8LELOSSQw9Li3lbPhfzq6UJzGQ5X6Zq1ms2sR8XWl3falGecFVJZxAfTiErd6eB1Vwywfq%2FzVKEvTeLFUVZv6ru67bulpJF6DBqe63uhqGvk8K4YZROp1Yd6SjDV8hiNNb4ZGG3vfPAE%2Bqq%2F%2FxDNVN2xp3D4papke3JGH%2BzaZ3y3ReY7tpogL1cvQtLBt%2BpeSAUxN%2BkTkFfyIZ9of%2BQB1UejFyt7MFqma6crx94GO%2FrDQfVLLg1DTwi6vpOWV53XDonUkTlJiA3PoRCITs3sJohmEu9u0zN11bT%2BBEcIaRCyCQ0hR9JWEXmQMA4RtUNRxjbYTQ4IRDzkLIlld23GRBBgRGgRN%2FrN3XIRbExq7k6EdFhV7JYqQPxdxMi%2BjXnemuDH53pyDRBxF3C0e1CwgyEGaRO0kBABEzP1rY805QyHFkkGOU0LewwolaIF78fadziOgA4r%2Fjp%2Bf9WpZxTMNuMrv9aw8k9TRXUEGfRiRQSLPRCBFaK6%2BDUOJ3DxS8JYNecQg2ZQwCcy1w4iwnnBnSx%2BrBdK1lPqdV%2B6XDLVSnDq%2FeXO9JetpP3qU4Ld9pB%2BuProZ8LkPt8yA9x3sCVMljHtNMsE6p0haTwpQr6kkAHSK1PRYaePJEsH9IxtELyS8Py%2B0cUGRm1e0IxuF%2FMZ7viOyQRxCgrgZZQ%2BhbfNO2O%2FQ9iuFtk%2Fx8u5Him3rOyg%2FeWyr9zTiIsnmxwX%2FWnvK%2FTT8EOFPb24cC6dfMOYJLlDHuZcNeVIis5FfLenOJ%2BSJ7fsdajxRdumr0mH28LoRXJYCqJhmefKs9zo0omo%2BvtBH2Xq1ncbLZTLybQVA509f4OYVRhgzK%2FkXJBgFTFrBB5Un8Epl%2FMPftNQyW%2BUjewJuXqGI84kq%2FNCu3%2BWb9nRsEnQc1FpZrlJwPvf%2BmXuXIYyGD1kyLxq6BDxADDvFo0sgIhSQTYc%2F1auaDhtLt3VIAr04xddBIQuT9RZD6OuooGvpKNlUg7UbwcKfg2DnQhwcdW3cGaMKKlFAnZ2%2Fw5ijnRnmQVN8JSFHkbMJK49FHfuhxImp85gUXwwd9G%2FDmZ29T9jhfOiZcQhFmznEaYSaxRmY%2BED3I0OfQz6JWERR2F4EbiERGC5%2BcpotdIPl5jcFHgP4TvHHICRyz9jJGl8rbQez135UdAbs1Zv31f26w6sdJfZ9ZPTSIHz%2B00BGKJLMKR45iOSIuKcoa25u12lACUe8%2FUmP9aVEoCBqjllEv9PATmkskENzYpLL3pjedSJwuhBP1qK7MwvIgT7cZosue8OzIi8hIUNh1JTId22UocD7EOkw9oZBiBwloT9HtnyL1pMTb76YtGo5ZDluiBL90rlrF%2FB0dMZISrnujIVLapvRNu6dik3Ousvn%2FyxzQMIiaq%2FUdFfWc%2FDK0cYECUIDsP5oPtuyHkuMBG6K%2F6bdm%2BgHTgG4bT7brpo338az1%2F8D)

First I thought that I create a DXL script but I think with DXL can not reach ALM server. So is there any (REST) API or Library for C# or Java to reach DOORS's requirements, ALM / Jazz team server and set the state of the requirement.

So the point, how can I modify DOORS requirements and read work items on Jazz Team Server in one java or c# application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to programmatically access DOORS is through DXL, there's no REST or other language library. (Would love to hear otherwise.)

One idea is to write DXL scripts that read/write environment variables and/or files, and then wrap them in DOS scripts that launches DOORS clients in batch mode. Your application can then use those scripts to transfer input parameters and data to/from DOORS.